# Loop in loop with facelets

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, facelets

I'm developing an application using `jsf2` and `facelets`. In one of my views I try to display data from a database and I use two nested loops. The second loop uses a var which is an attribute of the var declared for the first loop.

But it's not working.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{MyBean.Vect}" var="item">
     <h:outputText value="${item.attr}" /> <br />
     <ui:repeat value="#{item.nestedtVect}" var="product" >
         <h:outputText value="${product.name}" /> <br />
     </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

The first loop works but not both.

Comment: Isn't `nestedtVect` a typo? Have you posted your exact code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure `item.nestedtVect` is not null and actually has items? Your Facelet seems to be correct at first sight.

E.g. consider this minimal example:

Backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class NestedLoopBacking {

    String[][] items = { {"A", "B"}, {"1", "2", "3"} };

    public String[][] getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

Facelet:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:body>

        <ui:repeat value="#{nestedLoopBacking.items}" var="item">
            <ui:repeat value="#{item}" var="content">
                <h:outputText value="${content}" />
                <br />
            </ui:repeat>
        </ui:repeat>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

This Just Works™. You might want to put in an explicit test to see if your nested collection is empty or not:

```
<h:outputText value="Collection empty" rendered="#{empty item.nestedtVect}"/>
<h:outputText value="Collection not empty" rendered="#{!empty item.nestedtVect}"/>
```

p.s.

Unrelated to the question, but you might want to look at your naming. `MyBean.Vect` is not a really good name, and neither is `attr` in `item.attr`. Also, you seem to mix deferred and immediate syntax (`#{}` and `${}`) for no apparent reason.